# JDK Home path in eclipse will not change

Tags: java, eclipse

I have followed the instructions to direct eclipse to the virtual machine path of the JDK but for some reason when i clean the project and run make and deploy it shows that ant is still pointing to the jre in program files rather then the JDK specified and selected  following -

Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's > Add... For 'JRE Type' select 'Standard VM' > Next > Directory: select your JDK directory (instead of JR)

Is there something im missing? Im using windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Check the JVM settings in the Run configuration for Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRE/JDK used by Ant runs is configured in the run configuration for Ant.

Look in 'Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations...' and find your Ant build. Look in JRE tab for the configuration.